# Searching for tuples in python based on the first part

Tags: python, set

I am using python's set class. The set contains tuples `(id,name)`. Given an id how can I check whether that corresponds to one already in the set and do:

```
if id is not in the set by searching the tuples
add a new tuple (id,name) in the set
```

I am using sets because they are supposed to use a hashtable which is more efficient than a list and I am dealing with a lot of data (more than 50GB)

Comment: an example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: You should probably use a dictionnary instead of a set. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: As suggested it seems that a "dict" is a better data structure than a "set" in your case. You compare the tuples by the first element only, which means that you either have to use dict and have the first element as a key for fast look-up or use custom container that redefines `__eq__` and `__hash__` so that set's operations will take into account only the first element ("id").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to loop over *all* tuples in the set and test each one:

```
if not any(t[0] == id for t in tuple_set):
    tuple_set.add((id, some_name))
```

The [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) here will iterate over the generator expression given and short-circuit to return `True` as soon as a match is found.

If your tuples are always going to be unique based on the first element, then you probably want to use a custom class that implements [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) and [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

```
class Entry(object):
    __slots__ = ('id', 'name')  # save some memory
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id 
        self.name = name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Entry): return NotImplemented
        return self.id == other.id
    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self.id)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<{0}({1[0]!r}, {1[1]!r})>'.format(type(self).__name__, self)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return getattr(self, ('id', 'name')[index])
```

then use those in a set, after which you can use:

```
if Entry(id, some_name) in entries_set:
```

Demo:

```
>>> entries_set = {Entry('foo', 'bar'), Entry('foo', 'baz')}
>>> entries_set
set([<Entry('foo', 'baz')>])
>>> Entry('foo', 'spam') in entries_set
True
```

Another option is to just map ids to names in a *dictionary*; dictionaries are sets with values:

```
id_value_dictionary = {'id1': 'name1', 'id2': 'name2'}

if id not in id_value_dictionary:
    id_value_dictionary[id] = some_name
```

Comment: but then shouldn't I just use a list?

Comment: @user4636089: you may as well use a list then, yes. The `set()` won't help if your unique values are determined by the `id`.

Comment: Use a dict `{id: tuple}` or even `{id: name}`.

Answer (score 0):

in Python set and dict use a very similar implementation:

[Python collections complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

And they're both backed by an hashtable.

What you'd like to do is not suitable to set; use a dict with "id" as key and "name" as value, and use the setdefault method:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
d.setdefault("a", 5) # a will retain its original value
d.setdefault("d", 9) # the d key will be inserted with the passed value
```

In order to get the key-value tuples as you'd like, you can use the items() or iteritems() methods (which one depends on your requirements, the first creates a list, the second an iterable; the latter is probably better for very large datasets as it uses less memory).